# Can you have multiple BindingTypes on a Jax-WS Web Service?

Tags: java, json, jax-ws

I have a web service I have already written to handle SOAP requests, but I was wondering if I could add another binding type to have it use the Jax-WS JSON Binding made available via the jaxws-json.jar. So I am wondering if it is possible to have multiple binding types on a service.

Comment: why don't you use JAX-RS (Jersey) instead?

Comment: It is an existing service already called by external components.